# Upload photo to picasa from android?

Tags: android, google-api, image-uploading, picasa

I'm new to android programming. I'm looking for a simple way to send pictures to Picasa, I looked at a lot of projects on it. I'm just looking to send a JPEG or PNG button I click, sends and displays a message that it is OK.
I know that is required a Google API and client authentication, but a lot of people show the same Intention sent.
Please help (sorry for the english: P)

I found this:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse?repo=samples#hg/picasa-android-sample

Someone knows how to use it? But from the basics, I'm lost.

Answer (score 1):

The only existing code in online for uploading photos to Picasa is this one..

- [Picasa Photo Uploader](http://code.google.com/p/picasaphotouploader/source/browse/trunk/src/com/android/picasaphotouploader/ImageUploader.java)

Try with this one whether it can meet your requirements.If it does,then engage it with a button click event and display message on  notification.finished() event to ensure that the file has been uploaded.

Comment: I've seen this project already but he is in 2009. And was written up on Android 2.2. I wrote an application for 3 and up, and it must be some higher code or API which is better.

Answer (score 1):

Quite an old post, but just for future references, I was successful in directly using http post to upload my image to Picasa. Their own Java API keeps returning errors.

I've written about this method in detail [here](https://theneewpotato.wordpress.com/2017/08/02/android-using-picasa-api-to-upload-images/):

```
File image = new File("/path/to/image.jpg");
byte[] imageContent = null;
try {
    imageContent = Files.toByteArray(image);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // do something
}

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default/albumid/default");
httpPost.addHeader("Authorization",  "Bearer " + mAccessToken);
httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(imageContent));

try {
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    // log the response
    logd(EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()));
} catch (IOException e){
    // do something
}
```

This method uses Apache's HttpClient. If your Android version does not support it, you can still include this line in your Gradle file to compile it:

```
compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1'
```

Comment: Link as answers are best for comments not answers. I suggest editing the above answer to add the main parts so its in one place. The link doesn't contain that much code.